# Find and extract words from strings

Tags: php, recursion

I need to find and extract words (array) in a string. I tried many techniques, and I found how to find first occurrences, but can't get it to work recursively.

```
$uda_state = [
    "uda actif",
    "uda stagiaire",
    "stagiaire uda",
    "uda",
    "apprenti actra",
    "actra apprenti",
    "actra"
];

$arr = [
    '<p>Nothing here</p>',
    '<p>UDA Stagiaire et ACTRA</p>',
    '<p>Stagiaire UDA</p>',
    '<p>Should not pop</p>'
];

function contains($str, array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if ($pos = stripos($str,$a)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function extractWord($str, array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if ($pos = stripos($str, $a)) return $arr;
    }
}

function find_uda_actra($str, array $arr = []) {
    global $uda_state;

    if (contains($str, $uda_state)) {
        $word = extractWord($str, $uda_state);
        $arr[] = $word;
        $str = str_ireplace($word, '', $str);
        if ($str != '') {
            if (contains($str, $uda_state)) {
                list($str, $arr) = find_uda_actra($str, $arr);
            }
            else {
                return [$str, $arr];
            }
        } else {
            return [$str, $arr];
        }
    }

    return [$str, $arr];
}

foreach ($arr as $str) {
    list($content, $uda) = find_uda_actra($str);
    echo 'Content:'.PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($content);
    echo 'UDA:'.PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($uda);
}
```

All I get now is emptied content and the whole $uda_state in each $uda. I need only the one that was found.

[3v4l link for sandbox.](https://3v4l.org/h68vh)

Comment: Regex would work with this: `'#'.implode('|', $uda_state).'#i'` https://3v4l.org/j01C1

Comment: I was about to check my own question as answered, I found where I make my mistake, but I will update my code to use that since it will be faster than a loop! Thank you !